# Why iframe does not display HTML file?

Tags: html, iframe

I try to include HTML page by `SRC` using `iframe`:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" src="widget.html">
</iframe>
```

So, this way shows html file as simple text(code) in iframe

**HTML file:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="1404.34">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
    p.p2 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; line-height: 14.0px; font: 12.0px Helvetica; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000; min-height: 14.0px}
    span.s1 {font-kerning: none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<b>test page</b>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This question could use some more details

Comment: Which do you mean? I can show `widget.html` file

Comment: well it's just showing widget.html as plain text not the actual HTML?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question at all.

Comment: What you need more?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116614/discussion-between-charlie-fish-and-huligan).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for future reference if anyone else is having this issue, after discussing further and looking at the HTML it was found that the iFrame src didn't have the `<html>` tag surrounding it.